# I am getting error on bundle install in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

1. Retrying `git clone 'git://github.com/Azdaroth/simple-captcha.git' "/home/intrcity/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@ry_rails5/cache/bundler/git/simple-captcha-f06f0cfd255417fffe861c65e1badbe22e822021" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/Azdaroth/simple-captcha.git' "/home/intrcity/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@ry_rails5/cache/bundler/git/simple-captcha-f06f0cfd255417fffe861c65e1badbe22e822021" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/intrcity/ry_project/railyatri.railyatri_web has failed.fatal: remote error:
   The unauthenticated git protocol on port 9418 is no longer supported.
   Please see https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/ for more information.
2. Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/Azdaroth/simple-captcha.git' "/home/intrcity/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@ry_rails5/cache/bundler/git/simple-captcha-f06f0cfd255417fffe861c65e1badbe22e822021" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/intrcity/ry_project/railyatri.railyatri_web has failed.

Comment: github,.com turned off the `git://` protocol. Use `https://` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [github doocument](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) from 15th march github will permanently stop accepting `git://` protocol. You can change the url from `git://` to `https://`.

Refer this [github issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/959) for more info

Comment: Thanks, Vishal it works   [git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://]

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, could you please approve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably running an old version of git.

1. Ensure that you are using the latest git version
2. Add the git PPA using the terminal and update git using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
Sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

I hope this helps, Happy codding.